How to copy the fileshare as-is between the storage accounts using ADF Copy data pipeline?
I have the two storage accounts in two different subscriptions and each storage account has only one fileshare.
I don't want to give the fileshare names explicitly in the pipeline parameters with the names of source_fs, target_fs as shown in the 1st step of this stack overflow solution.
While creating the Linked Service itself, I have selected the file share.

So, How do I configure the Copy Data Pipeline without this dynamic parameters entering to the piepline. I just need to copy one fileshare data directly between the storage accounts.

Which type of data do you want copy from source to target?

It's a file share data, where data can be json or any other formats - In simple it is binary data.


It's a file share data, where data can be json or any other formats - In simple it is binary data.

To achieve your requirement, follow below procedure:
Here is the source file share data:

Create two file share linked services for source and sink as shown below:
Source linked service:

Sink linked service:

Create two binary datasets for source and sink as below:
Source dataset:

Sink dataset:

Use both linked services as source and sink for copy activity and configure source settings in copy activity as shown below:

Debug the pipeline, the data from source file share to target file share successfully as shown below:


Getting the solutions is one best thing here and also getting the points is also making me feel good. I think you're expert in azure data stream, thanks for your help. could you please upvote my questions too :-)
